# Console in iphone

Tags: iphone, console

When we are developing a application for iOS, we write some NSLog statements.

Now, when we actually deploy this code in iPhone,

- Where do all the statements print?
- How can we access the output in iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can debug the app while your device is connected with Xcode and check the NSLog in the console.
2. You can also check this NSLog when not connected with Xcode. You can access this in the organizer while your app is not in debug mode. Open Xcode and than open Organizer (CMD+Shift+2) and click the connected device with multiple option like Profile, Console, andDevice Log. When your app crashes, it displays the crash log on device Log while your app is running its NSLog display in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Just connect your iPhone to mac, set your building target to your device, you can see NSLog at your XCode console.(`Shift`+`Cmd`+`Y` to open it).
And if you need full information, open the XCode, then:

> 'Organizer' -> 'Devices'
>
> Choose your device at left sidebar, you'll find **Console** & **Device Logs**

Logs are all there. :)

Answer (score 1):

use Organizer, bundled with Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Phone Configuration Utility lets you easily create, maintain, encrypt, and install configuration profiles, track and install provisioning profiles and authorized applications, and capture device information including console logs.

It is available for Windows and Mac.

For Windows:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466

For Mac:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465